# Python: function to alter a global variable that is also parameter

Tags: python, function, global

```
def fxn(L):
    """ 
    """
    global L = 2

L = 1
fxn(L)
print(L)
```

I have a function like the one above. Assume I need the function to alter the global variable from within the function so that when I print L after calling fxn(L). I end up with the 2 rather than 1.

Is there any way to do this? I cant use global L in the function because L is also a parameter.

Comment: *Why* do you have to use the same name for both?  I could see why you might not be able to change the global, but why can't you change the parameter?

Comment: ^^ Yeah. I don't understand either why you can't change the `L` argument you are defining in your `fxn` method declaration.

Comment: Since you have asked, I have added the answer with a way to achieve this. But you should not use the same variable as global variable and the functional argument to the function using that global variable.

Comment: Yes, why don't you *return* a value and assign it to the global variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the same variable as global variable and the functional argument to the function using that global variable.

But since you have asked, you can do it using the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) and [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals). Below is the sample code:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> def var_test(x):
...     print('GLOBAL x: ', globals()['x'])
...     print('LOCAL x: ', locals()['x'])
...     globals()['x'] = 111
...     print('GLOBAL x: ', globals()['x'])
...     print('LOCAL x: ', locals()['x'])
...
>>> var_test(20)
GLOBAL x:  5
LOCAL x:  20
GLOBAL x:  111
LOCAL x:  20
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea, but there are ways, for example:

```
a = 5

def f(a):
    def change_a(value):
        global a
        a = value
    change_a(7)

f(0)

print(a)   # prints 7
```

In reality, there is seldom any need for writing to global variables. And then there is little chance that the global has the same name as a variable which just cannot change the name.

If you are in such a situation, ask yourself *"am i using `global` too often?"*

Comment: That's very sneaky.